# backgroundworker doesnt get progress info from another class

Tags: c#, class, user-interface, backgroundworker, exchange-server

i call this after a button click:

FORM1-Code:

```
{

   ProgressBar.Maximum = 500;    
   myArguments gifargs = new myArguments();    //class for passing arguments to the bgW    
   gifargs.InputFilePath = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); // input filepath    
   gifargs.OutputFilePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;        //output filepath    
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(gifargs);                // run bgW async with args   
}


// here is bgW doWork
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)   
{   
myArguments args = e.Argument as myArguments; //myArguments class
if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)    
{
  e.Cancel = true;
}
PictureHandler makeAnimatedGIf = new PictureHandler(); // creating new object    
makeAnimatedGIf.imageGif(args.InputFilePath,args.OutputFilePath); //call method with args

makeAnimatedGIf.GifProgress += new PictureHandler.myprogressgetter(this.GifProgressF1);

//add the delegate
```

works perfect until here

this is my Callback function which should update bgW.ReportProgress

but it never gets there?!

```
private void GifProgressF1(int i)
{
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
            ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           ProgressBar.Value = 0;
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process canceled!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process complete!");
            }

        }
```

<----Picturehandler.cs-Code----->

//Delegate definition in my Picturehandler class

```
public delegate void myprogressgetter(int i);

public myprogressgetter GifProgress;








public void imageGif(string input, string output)
    {
        Process imagemagick = new Process();
        imagemagick.StartInfo.FileName = "convert.exe";
        imagemagick.StartInfo.Arguments = "-monitor -delay 1 " + input + " +map " + output;
        imagemagick.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        imagemagick.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        imagemagick.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        imagemagick.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        imagemagick.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        imagemagick.Start();
        StreamReader ima = imagemagick.StandardError;
        bool assign2 = false;

        do
        {
            string consolausgabe = ima.ReadLine();
            if (consolausgabe.Contains("Reduce") == true)
            {
                assign2 = true;
            }
            gifprocess(consolausgabe, assign2);

        } while (!ima.EndOfStream);
        imagemagick.WaitForExit();
        imagemagick.Close();
    }

 private void gifprocess(string cline, bool zähl)
    {
        if (cline.Contains("Load"))
        {
            string a1 = cline;
            string[] a11 = a1.Split(new char[] { ':', ',' });
            string a12 = a11[3];
            string[] a13 = a12.Split(new char[] { '%' });
            int load1 = Convert.ToInt32(a13[0]);
            GifProgress(load1;)  //<<<<<------------- this will give me an exception
            // Visual Studio says GifProgress = null in Autos
```

}

now if i call `GifProgress(100)` or any other integer, I get exception(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.), progressbar gets never updated.

The progress information from the picturehandler class wont get to the UI, I tried for 2 days now.

I use same code to get textbox.text from form2 and callback function works just fine.
WorkerReportProgress = TRUE.

Comment: Where does `PictureHandler` class come from?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your `DoWork` method would have a loop in it. Each iteration of the loop could finish with a call to `ReportProgress`, which would cause the stuff in `ProgressChanged` to run.

Since you're just running a few lines of code, use the `RunWorkerCompleted` to set the progress indicator and forget `ReportProgress` altogether.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker) I used to understand the BackgroundWorker better, if it helps...

Unless maybe you're doing what you're doing because your background worker thread exits before `makeAnimatedGIf.imageGif` is finished doing whatever it does...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your BackgroundWorker's WorkerReportsProgress property is set to true. Default is false

Comment: Hello, WorkerReportsProgress = true and WorkerSupportsCancellation = true.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set WorkerReportsProgress to true and use Invoke() to update the progressbar from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you expect to be called, `GifProgressF1` is only referenced as a call back for an instance of `PictureHandler' class. Where and how this call back is called in entirely up to that class then. However from your description it is not clear where this class comes from or what it does. I'd suggest referring either to the class documentation or source code, to find exactly when this callback is supposed to be called and going from there.

Comment: i added the relevant part of picturehandler class